# Time Complexity in code?

Tags: c, algorithm, time-complexity, big-o, hamiltonian-cycle

I have fun1 calls `foo1()` which takes `O(n^6 + m^4)`. What do you think the time complexity of `fun1`? My guess is it would be `O(2n^6 + m^4)` !!

```
int fun1(int n, int G[MAX][MAX])
{
  int x, ans;
  if(n < 2)
     return 1;
  for(x = 0; x < n; x++){
    G[n][x] = G[x][n] = 1;
  }
  ans = foo1(n+1, G);
  return ans;
}
```

Also fun2 calls foo2() which takes O(n^3 + m^2). What do you think the time complexity of fun2? My guess is O(n^3 + m^2 + 2n^2) !!

```
 int fun2(int n, int G[MAX][MAX])
 {
   int x, y, i, j;
   int ans = y = 0;
   int arr[MAX][MAX] = {};
   for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
     for(j = 0; j < n; j++)
       arr[i][j] = G[i][j];
   }

   if(n <= 2)
     return 0;
   for(x = 0; x < n; x++){
     if(arr[y][x] && arr[x][y]){
       arr[y][x] = arr[x][y] = 0;
       arr[n+1][x] = arr[x][n+1] = 1;
       arr[y][n] = arr[n][y] = 1;
       if(foo2(n+2, arr))
         ans = 1;
       arr[n][y] = arr[y][n] = 0;
       arr[n+1][x] = arr[x][n+1] = 0;
       arr[y][x] = arr[x][y] = 1;
       if(ans == 1)
         break;
     }    
   }
   return ans;
  }
```

Am I right?

Comment: Any particular reasons you came up with those for answers, or were they truly random guesses? Such reasoning belongs *in your question*.

Comment: why do you guess? _fun1_ does some minor calculations and then calls _foo(n+1, G)_ which has the time-comp. of _O((n+1)^6 + m^4)_ == _O(n^6 + m^4)_

Comment: for the first one I just added one since there's only 1 loop. The 2nd function I added n^2 + n since there's a double loop and a separate single loop .

Comment: For complexity we care about the "big picture". If something is `n^3 + n` the `+ n` is just ignored because `n` is much smaller than `n^3`. So ` O(n^3 + m^2 + 2n^2)` would just be ` O(n^3 + m^2)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `fun1()`, I do not agree with you. In the body of the function there is a for loop that takes O(n) and then `foo1(n+1, G)`, which takes O((n+1)<sup>6</sup> + m<sup>4</sup>). Putting them together, we get:

> O(n) + O((n+1)<sup>6</sup> + m<sup>4</sup>) = O(n) + O(n<sup>6</sup> + m<sup>4</sup>) = O(n<sup>6</sup> + m<sup>4</sup>)

---

I am afraid I do not agree with your second guess either, since what you have there is two for loops, which made you guessed what you guessed.

However, please notice that the second [for-loop](/questions/tagged/for-loop) calls `foo2(n+2, arr)` in its body. As a result, `foo2()` will be called `n` times!

Putting everything together, we have:

> first for loop + second for loop = O(n) + O(n(n + 2)<sup>3</sup> +
>   nm<sup>2</sup>) = O(n) + O(n<sup>4</sup> + nm<sup>2</sup>) = O(n<sup>4</sup> + nm<sup>2</sup>)

Comment: Agree. For the second example the important part is that `foo2` is called with the same parameters every time. Consequently it is just `n` times the complexity of `foo2`. Had the call been `foo2(x+2, arr)`, it would have given a different result.

Comment: Correct @4386427, thank you for your comment and upvote!